# How to use/create a more generic ccall in Julia?

Tags: c, julia

I'd like to call a function that calls a c function, but I want to be able to swap out the actual C function

```
function Ccall(fn)
    ... more code 1 ...    
    ccall((fn, libc), Int32, ()) 
    ... more code 2 ...
end
```

where the `more code` part is always the same but `fn` can change.
For a simple example, I try to call this Ccall function

```
f = "clock" |> Symbol
Ccall(f)
```

but I get an error message. Also tried

```
function Ccall(fn)
    ... more code 1 ...    
    ccall(fn, Int32, ()) 
    ... more code 2 ...
end
```

with

```
const f = ("clock" |> Symbol, "libc")
Ccall(f)
```

but no luck, `f` is not a constant expression, what it should be, just because I put a `const` in front.

Is there a way of ccall-ing with the above genericity? If so, how?

Comment: how about using macros to wrap those c functions? take a look at [this](https://github.com/JuliaGL/ModernGL.jl/blob/master/src/glFunctions.jl).

Answer (score 5):

`ccall` requires an expression, not a value---it's a little bit like a macro in that regard. You can generate the appropriate expressions (see the HDF5.jl package for one example), but your best bet is probably to create one wrapper-function per C function as Gnimuc Key suggested.